# How to update log4net configuration programatically

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have found lot of ways to generate the full `log4net` configuration programmatically but could not find anywhere the way to update the existing configuration programmatically.

I am trying this in my `global.asax.cs` file

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
var appender = (log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)hierarchy.Root.GetAppender("NormalLogFileAppender");
if (appender != null)
{
    appender.ClearFilters();

    var filter = new log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter();
    filter.LevelMin = Level.Info;
    filter.LevelMax = Level.Emergency;
    filter.AcceptOnMatch = true;

    appender.AddFilter(filter);
    appender.ActivateOptions();
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

It reads the appender, but does not update it.

I found this question,

[How can I programmatically update log4net configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602613/how-can-i-programmatically-update-log4net-configuration-file)

according to this, there is no such standard way to do this.

It there any way now?

Comment: Is the intent to make a log4net config generator for other apps?  Otherwise why not just stick to _config-via-code?_

Comment: @MickyD - I want to update the minLevel of the filter programmatically based on some variable value